# VBA - Error Array Double as Function Argument

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a function with an array as input. However, I'm receiving `#VALUE!` error. The function code is as follows:

```
Function foo(x() As Double) As Double
    foo = x(1) + x(2)
End Function
```

The call is done with the following formula:

```
=foo($E$8:$E$9)
```

E8 and E9 correspond to two numbers.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Going from memory here... but I think you might be getting a 2D array here instead of the 1D array you are expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$E$8:$E$9` is of type `Range` and not an array of type `Double`. Your UDF fails there.

---

Once you change your param type to `Range` then it will work for  `x(1) + x(2)` as long as you pass 2X1 (2Rows, 1Column) range with numeric values.

```
Function foo(rng As Range) As Double
    foo = rng(1) + rng(2)
End Function
```

---

To make a meaningful UDF you will need to check the dimensions, data types of the range in your code.

Comment: Upvoted, but the amount of implicit conversions and implicit default member calls going on in this code is.... scary.

Comment: @Mat'sMug agreed. the `foo = rng(1) + rng(2)` part is just to demonstrate that the verty first issue with OP's code is parameters data type.  Just using 'Range` as the input, one certainly needs handle dimensions, data types etc to come up with something useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a variant as the parameter: more efficient and less error prone

```
    Function foo(x As Variant) As Double
    x=x.value2
    foo = x(1, 1) + x(2, 1)
    End Function
```

Comment: Sorry... how is working with late-bound member calls, implicit conversions and implicit default member calls any more efficient than working with an early-bound `Range`? The UDF is clearly given a `Range` here. Losing IntelliSense is probably a bad idea when you're a green coder that doesn't know all that's going on under the hood.

Comment: forgot to add the conversion - its usually much faster to convert a range to a variant array than to make multiple calls to a range object. Also its then easier to generalise the code to handle constant array and subexpression parameters etc.

Comment: Agreed, working with a variant 2D array is definitely a good approach (if not the best) - but then taking a `Variant` parameter becomes misleading if the function really only works with a `Variant/Range` - I'd take a `Range` instead, and have the array be a local variable instead if reassigning the parameter, which is implicitly passed by reference, so using that UDF in regular VBA code would have unintended consequences in the calling code; a rather confusing runtime *type mismatch*, probably.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use variant as parameter. It can be array and Range.
Test if it is a single cell/value, it will be not converted to array. In this case return the value of the cell.
Test if it is Range object. If it is the case convert it to array. Array is quick.

For summing I would loop through the array with for each to avoid any complication of indexing in the array. (One or two dimensional).
Additionally the values shall be tested if they are numbers.
The small sub is for testing the function call from a sub.

```
Function foo(x As Variant) As Double
    If VarType(x) < vbArray Then 'Single element
        foo = IIf(IsNumeric(x), x, 0) ' if x is number return x else 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    If TypeName(x) = "Range" Then x = x.Value2 ' if Range converts to array
    Dim v As Variant
    ' sum all values of x
    For Each v In x
        'sum only numbers, ignor anything else
        If IsNumeric(v) Then foo = foo + v
    Next v
End Function

Sub testFoo()
    'Test for non Range
    Debug.Print foo(Array(1, 34, 5)) 'Test for array
    Debug.Print foo(5.2) ' Test for a number
    Debug.Print foo("Apple") ' Test for not number
End Sub
```

Results:

> 40;  5,2;  0